# Using Prawn with rails app: Send generated pdf file to user's downloads folder instead of app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

In a controller I have the following line in one of the actions:

```
def some_action
  @blog = Blog.find(11)
  PdfSingleBlog.new(@blog).print
end
```

That `PDfSingleBlog` is just a PORO class acting as a service.  The service's job is obviously to generate a pdf of this blog and it is supposed to send that pdf to the user's downloads folder. That code is located here:

```
#app/services/pdf_single_blog.rb
class PdfSingleBlog

  def initialize(blog)
    @blog = blog
  end

  def print
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    pdf.text "Blog Name: #{@blog.name}"
    pdf.text "Description: #{@blog.description}"
    pdf.render_file "blog_info.pdf"
  end
end
```

The pdf is successfully generated, however it is not sending it to the user's downloads folder.  Instead it is saving it to the directory of the application on the server.

How do I actually send the generated pdf to the user's downloads folder?

[PDF of prawn manual found here](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf)

---

**Updated with Answer below:**

---

```
def some_action
  @blog = Blog.find(11)
  blog_pdf = PdfSingleBlog.new(@blog).prepare_for_print
  send_data blog_pdf.render, filename: "blog.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
end

#app/services/pdf_single_blog.rb
class PdfSingleBlog

  attr_reader :blog
  def initialize(blog)
    @blog = blog
  end

  def prepare_for_print
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    pdf.text "Blog Name: #{@blog.name}"
    pdf.text "Description: #{@blog.description}"
    return pdf
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to tell it to send via `send_file` or preferentially `send_data` and just stream it to the user this way there is no need to store it on the server at all. [Rails streaming documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html)

Comment: @engineersmnky I replaced `pdf.render_file "blog_info.pdf"` with:  
      `send_data pdf.render, filename: "blog_info.pdf"`  and it gave me: `undefined method `send_data'`

Comment: `send_data` would need to be in the controller not the model. You would pass the data back from the model to the controller and then send the data.

Comment: ok, I'll try `send_file` and try to get that working

Comment: @engineersmnky I figured it out with your guidance.  Please post something relevant as an answer so I can give you credit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are generating the file right now you are not actually sending it to the browser. While you can use `send_file` to send the locally generated file to the browser this will require you to generate the file and save it locally.

Since this file is being generated on the fly I would recommend `send_data` instead to avoid the need to save the file at all.

You can do this by making the following modifications

In Your Controller:

```
def some_action
  @blog = Blog.find(11)
  send_data PdfSingleBlog.new(@blog).print_data, filename:'blog.pdf', type: "application/pdf", disposition: :attachment
end
```

In Your Model:

```
class PdfSingleBlog

  def print_data
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    pdf.text "Blog Name: #{@blog.name}"
    pdf.text "Description: #{@blog.description}"
    pdf.render
  end
end
```

This will stream the pdf to the browser as an attachment which will prompt the end user to either open or download the file.